# PostgreSQL, sort DESC places null first

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query:

```
select (buyins + buyouts) AS amount from invoice_records where billing_id = 'XYZ' order by amount desc;
```

Which gives me this result:

```
 amount
------------

     207060 
     198599 
     198599
```

So an empty line is placed first, and not 207060?

Comment: Oh, found the `NULLS LAST`option. Trying that...

Comment: You can answer your own question in case someone else runs into the same problem.